# Bot identifies entity in api.ai console but not in fb messenger

Tags: facebook-messenger, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot

I want to identify either city, state or pincode.

- If I try "pizza stores in sunnyvale" in api.ai console it identifies "sunnyvale" as city.
- If I try  "pizza stores in sunnyvale" in FB Messenger it is not identifying "sunnyvale" as city.

Rest all things are working fine.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: There are cases where things work in the console but not when called from the front end, as well as cases where they might work on one server but not another (??!) - see [this thread](https://discuss.api.ai/t/different-servers-same-agent-different-response/9477)

Comment: Can you see the requests from the FB messenger bot in API.AI's Training or history features?  Does the training or history feature in API.AI indicate that the query is it matched to the correct intent?   

https://api.ai/docs/training

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs, I got this issue solved by using a webhook for Facebook messenger instead of using webhook for API.ai. Things are working fine in both console and messenger.